# When installing virtualbox slack is uninstalled on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I've installed Slack. It's running fine until I decided to install Virtualbox. Then somehow Slack is uninstalled.

Seems like I cant have both Slack and Virtualbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered this problem. I recommend you uninstall Slack, and install Virtualbox. Then proceed to install Slack through their snap, you might be able to find it on the Ubuntu Software Store (make sure the source is snap) or just by running `sudo snap install slack`

I don't really like snap apps, but I'm glad that they can isolate apps so we can have both Slack and Virtualbox.